# Structuring an application that reads from a .properties file

Tags: design, object-oriented

I have a Java app with three classes: `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz`. All three depend on a bunch of what are currently constants defined in each class in order to determine how to run. On top of that, `Baz` interacts with a number of builder classes that need to be set up in various ways.

I'd like to refactor out all of the configuration info in to a .properties file so that I don't have to recompile every time I change a constant.

But I'm not sure how to structure it:

Do I have a `ConfigInfoSingleton` that holds all of the parameters of the application in static properties, and have other classes ask it for information when they need it? That seems wrong, as it introduces global state.

Do I pass around a `ConfigInfoMap` as a parameter to all of the classes that need that info? Then I need to have `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` parsing strings in order to decide what they're going to do, and that seems very wrong. Especially in the case of `Baz`, where I can't just pass around values, but I need to use `switch` statements on configuration info to determine builder method calls.

Do I parse the info in a different class, and have that class tell the others how to set themselves up? Then I have a class that needs to know about everyone else's implementation details, which seems wrong, but less so than the other options.

This seems like a really basic question but I'm not sure how to proceed in terms of good software design, and I haven't had much luck Googling. Whats the "right" thing to do?

Comment: "Then I need to have Foo, Bar, and Baz parsing strings in order to decide what they're going to do, and that seems very wrong." Parsing strings? Why? You can do all the parsing up front.

Comment: @Doval And then pass around enums or something like that?

Comment: Right. Parse the file, then create an object that represents the configuration file. The object's fields can be enums for config properties that only have a small set of choices.

Comment: Okay -- I was vaguely uncomfortable with this idea because it seemed like that would be leaking everyone's implementation details to the configuration file object. But maybe that's not so much of a big deal?

Comment: Constructor arguments aren't implementation details. Otherwise, every object leaks its implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Doval mentions you could parse your `*.properties` file and create a class that represents your properties and then pass it along to your classes.

A different approach is also to look into a framework that can handle this for you. Spring does not only inject your dependencies but also handles properties very well. [This questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259819/how-to-read-values-from-properties-file) gives a good example on how to use Spring together with `*.properties` files.

There is also less intrusive libraries available such as [Owner](http://owner.aeonbits.org) that supports live reloading of your properties amongst [other things](http://owner.aeonbits.org/docs/reload/).

Comment: Upvote for mentioning the Spring approach to the configuration topic.

Answer (score 1):

Parse the config file and create an object representing the config file's values. Then you can decide how to construct `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` based on the the values of the object's fields.

Answer (score 1):

Been there. Done that.

What I did when I had a similar situation was:

Regarding the configuration:

- Created a wrapper around a `Properties` class, I called that wrapper `Context`
- That wrapper reads and parses the property file
- I created a `ContextDependand` interface with a `setContext(Context c)` method
- I have `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` implement that interface
- I inject that `Context` object into my `Foo`, `Bar` and `Baz` classes so they can acces it without it being a Singleton

Regarding the creation problem:

- I used the `Builder pattern`
- I created a Builder interface with just a build method
- Created a FooBuilder, a BarBuilder, a BazBuilder, etc. that implement Builder and return an object which is a superclass of my other classes or an interface they implements
- I added each builder to a HashMap with a key, like `map.put('FOOBUILDER',new FooBuilder())`
- Then, instead of a long `case` structure, I just look up the builder in the `HashMap` and get it build the object for me, or I traverse the hash and build all of them
- That way I tell in the properties files what objects of a collection to build and that can be done without recompiling

If the Builder part is not want you were asking for, at least try the property wrapper / context injection part.